# Using sqlite to dynamically create tables in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So my fundamentals of creating and manipulating databases are a bit messed up. My aim here is that whenever the app is launched, the user is allowed to specify a table name, and whatever data is then collected is put into that table.

However, I'm confused as to how to do this. Do I simply pass the value of a user entered variable as the table name in my contentprovider class and execute sqlite statements to create it?

I've read/reading the documentation already, so if anyone has any insight or clarity, or even better, code snippets, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use one table, and create a value that stands for the current app-session, and insert that value with each row. This would make your code simpler, and would still allow you to segregate/filter out the values from a particular app-session.  If you want to give the user the ability to enter the value (as you are giving them the ability to choose the table name) you'd just want to check to see if that value had already been used, just as you would have to see if the table-name had already been used.

Comment: I actually want to log a continous series of data points for each session. For example, if we say each session stands for a different route you take to rach a place everyday, I want to log the latitude and longitude points at a certain polling interval. I can't use different columns since I dont know how many points there will be to log from beforehand. Hence I wanted each route taken to be a different table, with the lat and long columns